# Hibernate beginner

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, netbeans

I'm currently trying to learn to use Hibernate to store objects in a database.  I've been working through a tutorial at https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html and I'm trying to create an XML file for a very simple class and table.  However I'm just totally unable to get it to work and I'm now really getting frustrated.  I just can't get it to work.

The database is Postgres 9.2, the class is one I wrote myself and the version of Hibernate is the one that ships with Netbeans 7.3 (3.2, I believe).

The table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sellable.manufacturers
(
  mfr_id serial NOT NULL, -- Manufacturer ID
  mfr_name character varying(127) NOT NULL, -- Manufacturer name
  CONSTRAINT manufacturers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mfr_id),
  CONSTRAINT manufacturers_mfr_name_key UNIQUE (mfr_name)
);
```

The class I'm trying to map it to is as follows:

```
package bikeshop.sellable;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Manufacturer implements Serializable {
    private Integer mfrId   = null;
    private String  mfrName = null;

    public Integer getMfrId () {
        return this.mfrId;
    }

    public String getMfrName () {
        return this.mfrName;
    }

    public void setMfrName (String MfrName) {
        this.mfrName    = MfrName;
    }
}
```

The XML for the Hibernate mapping is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Aug 21, 2013 7:20:20 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bikeshop.sellable.Manufacturer" table="manufacturers" schema="sellable">
        <comment>Product manufacturers</comment>
        <id name="mfrId" type="int">
            <column name="mfr_id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="mfrName" type="string">
            <column name="mfr_name" length="127" not-null="true" unique="true">
                <comment>Manufacturer name</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the Hibernate project config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bikeshop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">bikeshop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">bikeshop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="bikeshop.sellable.Manufacturer" file="" jar="" package="" resource="bikeshop/mappings/Manufacturers.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="bikeshop/mappings/Sellables.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I try using the HQL query editor, all I get is the query "select from" displayed, which obviously can't be executed.  Attempting to execute it results in an exception.

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Why is this failing to generate a valid SQL query?  What am I missing?

EDIT: I've been trying to get this to work, now I'm getting a different error.  The HQL query window now displays the message "Unable to retrieve data from the database." and the exception has changed to "org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property mfrId in class bikeshop.sellable.Manufacturer"

The config file has changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bikeshop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">bikeshop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">bikeshop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="bikeshop.sellable.Manufacturer" file="" jar="" package="bikeshop.sellable" resource="bikeshop/mappings/manufacturer.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and the mapping file has changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="bikeshop.sellable.Manufacturer" table="manufacturers" schema="sellable">
        <comment>Product manufacturers</comment>
        <id name="mfrId" type="int">
            <column name="mfr_id" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="mfrName" type="string">
            <column name="mfr_name" length="127" not-null="true" unique="true">
                <comment>Manufacturer name</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

EDIT 2: As a last ditch attempt I made all the Manufacturer members public and changed the access type to field in the XML.

Now the HQL query works and returns results.  But I obviously don't want to take that approach, public fields are a horrible idea!

Comment: Is it the query or the query editor that you are having problem with?

Comment: I type "from Manufacturer" into the editor, the query it generates is "select from"

Comment: Just a guess but perhaps you need to fully qualify Manufacturer with its package name.

Comment: I've been fooling around with it and now I get a different error about a missing setter.  I put a setter in for the manufacturer ID even though it's supposed to be set by the DB and not be editable, but I still get the setter error

Comment: If I make the class fields public and change the XML to use fields instead of getters/setters it works and executes a query successfully.  However I obviously don't want public fields, that's the absolute last thing I want to have to do

Comment: It's now working.  In spite of the fact I literally changed nothing!  This is really getting frustrating.  If I don't know why it failed to work before now I can't avoid the same issue cropping up again.

Comment: Use a more recent tutorial, which uses JPA annotations to define the mapping rather than XML files. XML files are an old, obsolete way of defining the mapping. Annotations are the standard, easier, more readable way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that the HQL editor doesn't get updated classes or metadata all the time when you make changes to the class or its metadata, it also seems that this can happen regardless of whether you use an external XML file or inline annotations.

The only workaround I've found so far is to quit Netbeans and restart it.  This makes the HQL query editor update, but is obviously quite annoying.